# Generating constructor in Scala in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, constructor, intellij-idea

In Java it's possible to just select *"create constructor matching super"* (or something pretty similar) and it automatically creates constructor. Is something like that available for Scala?

Example:

```
class Foo(a:Int, b:Int)
class Bar extends Foo
```

I'd just hit some hotkey on `Bar` and it would generate this:

```
class Bar(a:Int, b:Int) extends Foo(a:Int, b:Int)
```

Comment: I don't use IntellJ, so I don't have an answer.  However, I would not be surprised if there are no tools for generating Scala code like this.  One of Scala's design goals is to avoid the need for boiler-plate code, so I can imagine that no one has taken the time to build Scala-generation tools.

Comment: @barnesjd "avoid the need for boiler-plate code" - unfortunately when one must build on top of java classes designed some way, one cannot avoid this boiler-plate code...

Comment: Even without building on top of Java classes, you can't avoid calling the constructor of the superclass with the right params. It's already much shorter than in Java though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the IntelliJ IDEA scala plugin version 0.22.302 nothing has changed in code generation functionality. It has only got override & implement methods, companion object and toString options under code generation and no construction generation support yet.

Comment: Is this still up-to-date?